# Cauchy Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the circle $c(z_{0},r):[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the parametrisation $t\rightarrow z_{0}+r\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}$, calculate the integral $$\oint_{c(2,1)} \frac{z^{7}+1}{z^{2}(z^{4}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

If I understood correctly, I first have to the roots of the denominator and to find where the function is not analytic (out of the given circle). Then, I need to "send" it to the numerator and call it $f(z)$. What to do later is pretty clear -- using of Cauchy's formula for calculating it. Is this idea correct? But what can I do with the parametrisation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of the idea.  First thing is to find the poles, which are at $z=0$ (twice), $z=e^{\pm i \pi/4}$, and $z=e^{\pm i 3 \pi/4}$.  The next question to ask is, which of these poles are contained within my contour?  Your contour is $|z-2| = 1$.  Clearly $z=0$ is outside of this contour.  The other poles are contained within the unit circle centered at the origin, which is also outside of the contour.  Thus, the integrand is analytic within the contour, and the integral is zero by Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: Actually, may i ask something again: $z=0$ is clear, but how did you get $z=e^{\pm i\pi/4 }$ and $z=e^{\pm i3\pi/4 }$?

Comment: Roots of $z^4+1=0$.  $(e^{\pm i \pi/4})^4 = e^{\pm i \pi} = -1$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your understanding: *"If i undestood correct the Cauchy integration, here i have to find the roots of the denominator and to find where the function is not analytic (out of the given circle). Then i have to "send" it to the numerator and call it f(z)f(z),"*

Please note that you should find the poles **inside** not outside of the given circle.